# Terraform : How to bind Azure Service Bus Namespace to a VNet?

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

Using terraform, we have setup service endpoint from our VNet to service bus.  However, we now want to bind the service bus namespace to our vnet so no other networks can access that servic bus namespace.

Microsoft describes how to do the bind with ARM template [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-service-endpoints#binding-service-bus-to-virtual-networks).

How do you accomplish this using native terraform (no ARM template)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now possible using the [servicebus_namespace_network_rule_set](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/servicebus_namespace_network_rule_set) which was released in [v2.7.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/v2.7.0/CHANGELOG.md) of the provider.

You can also assign private endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the [module reference](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/servicebus_namespace.html) this is not yet possible with native terraform. This is not uncommon, many things are not possible with terraform in Azure.